# Correct way to unit test/mock shared export function using props from components - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my React project, I have a shared exported function:

```
//shared_functions.js
export function buildEndpoint(region, methodName) {
   return (region in this.props.regionalEndpointsMap ? this.props.regionalEndpointsMap[region] : this.props.regionalEndpointsMap["default"]) + "/" + methodName;
}
```

that's used and imported in multiple components such as:

```
//SomeComponent.jsx
import { buildEndpoint } from 'src/util/shared_functions';
....
handleSubmit = async event => {
   let response = await fetch(buildEndpoint(this.state.region, 'methodName'), {
....
```

The problem is I'm having trouble unit testing this function due to this.props.regionalEndpointsMap in the buildEndpoint function.

My question is what would be the correct way to unit test this function following best practices? Unit test it independently of any component that uses it? Test it from a component that uses it? Haven't been able to find a way to mock this.props.regionalEndpoints when trying to test the function independently, and when trying to test it from a component, the function is unrecognized:

```
//test.jsx
....
//props contains regionalEndpointsMap
wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent {...props} />);
wrapper.instance().buildEndpoint('region', 'method')
//buildEndpoint is unrecognized
```

And as another question that may make the above a moot point, okay to try and access a property (props) in an exported function even though it's not guaranteed to have that property in a component it's used in? Or is it frowned upon? Would it be better to create a base component class with this function and make it the parent to the component classes that use it?

Sorry if these sound like dumb questions, new to React and unit testing with jest and enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

To test the function independently you could mock it, something like this:

```
import { buildEndpoint } from 'src/util/shared_functions';

...

let result = ({
                props : {regionalEndpointsMap : {default : 'd'} }, 
                buildEndpoint : buildEndpoint 
              }).buildEndpoint("r", "m")
```

Personally though I would pass in regionalEndpointsMap to the function to avoid the need to access the `this` context.

Comment: Worked like a charm, but after further discussion with teammates decided not to access "this" in the helper function. Thank you